# Default login shell ksh

Tags: command-line, ksh

I want to set the default login shell to the Korn shell (ksh) but `chsh` doesn't recognize `/bin/ksh` as a shell.

`/bin/ksh` has been loaded.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact error message you get from `chsh`. Also clarify what you mean by "/bin/ksh has been loaded".

Comment: Add the exact command you ran as well as the full path to ksh (it may in /bin)

Answer (score 4):

The desired shell's full path must be added to the `/etc/shells` file - from `man shells`

```
DESCRIPTION
       /etc/shells  is  a text file which contains the full pathnames of valid
       login shells.  This file is consulted by chsh(1) and  available  to  be
       queried by other programs.
```

Comment: That and the path must be correct.